# Tortoise SVN create a new branch with same content

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using tortoise SVN and I want to create a new branchwith the similar contents of the current branch. I have a group of developers which would work on that branch of application.

The contents of the current branch is in **GigaBytes** so copying and pasting and then adding it to repository would take a very long time.

Is there a way to skip adding it to the repository and create some kind of a mirror copy directly? Can I do it directly on the server if that does not take that much time?

Thanks

Comment: You can create a branch in the repository using the Repo Browser. You'll still need to check out a copy in order to make any changes to it though.

Comment: But if those developers already have a working copy of main branch they can just [switch to a new branch](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html#tsvn-dug-switch-1), without much network traffic.

Answer (score 1):

If you use svn copy command properly it will create a branch without actually creating a physical copy of every file in your repository. They call it "cheap copies". The creation is almost instantaneous and is backed by the revision on which branch is based off.

type this command in console for understanding options in detail.

```
svn copy --help
```

also see these links very good resource for working with svn.
**for 1.7**
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.using.html.  
**for 1.8**
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.using.html

In the example below it's creating a branch using cheap copies **Not creating a duplicate copy**. Switch -m is to specify "Comment for this commit"
and @200 is  the revision from which you want to create branch. Hope this helps :)

```
$ svn copy http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/trunk@200 \
       http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/branches/my-calc-branch \
       -m "Creating a private branch of /calc/trunk."
```